# shift key (both) on keyboard error

Tags: linux, windows, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-layout

the problem is in my shift key, when I want to insert a symbol into a row I have to use the up arrow key first (which means I move to the top row) then press shift and then the symbol I go to, my right shift is like the page down button but in combination with the shift key.

while my left shift key, when I press shift left it's like the home key, but in combination with the shift key, so the cursor will return to the beginning of the line(same line). my initial machine is windows7 and my keyboard language is US, and the machine I'm using now is kali linux, I thought by switching machines everything would be fine, but apparently the problem still persists, so I sometimes get overwhelmed in writing code

I've tried to change the keyboard language in kali linux even on my windows7, and the result is still the same, it can't be the hardware, because in my opinion everything is normal.

anyone can help me?

Comment: Testing another keyboard will confirm or contradict your opinion.

Comment: i just have 1 keyboard, it's also default keyboard

Comment: Then your guess is as good as ours.

Comment: Which application are you using and how are you doing the input. I don't understand specifically the part about "up arrow key first (which means I move to the top row)".

Comment: ohh, sorry about that, oke for an example like this

**1 bla bla bla bla**
**2 bla bla bla bla ()**

see those brackets?, I added it on the first line, but what appears instead on the second line, as if my right shift key becomes another function, which should be where I add a symbol, then what appears is on that line too, but this is not, even the one that appears on the bottom line

Comment: Are you using a US QWERTY layout? If it occurs across different OSes it can only be one of two things: keyboard profile being used by the OS or a bad keyboard. if you're using the default US QWERTY keyboard profile and have not made any changes to the profile, it's likely a bad keyboard - the best way to determine the latter is trying a known-good keyboard _(if a laptop, and external USB keyboard)_, however if one isn't currently available, run the BIOS/UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics for the keyboard

Comment: Two almost identical questions & a clarification comment & I still have absolutely no clue exactly what it is you're trying to tell us. All this 'bottom/second line' bit is completely incomprehensible. Until you try another keyboard you have not even a basic comparison test.